# jquery autosize web interface?

Tags: jquery, layout, user-interface, autosize

I have been designing with jquery and using the jquery UI widgets .. but always been designing for 1024 x 768 ...

Is there any tricks or plugins (preferably that work with jquery UI) to automatically resize elements of my interface ...

that way when somebody views it at a higher resolution it doesn't look so small..

Anybody have any tips on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've not had a chance to mess with jQuery that much but ExtJS has a nice concept of [Layouts](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html) that would work perfectly (I only mention this cause I believe you are looking for something like those layouts but for jQuery). Looking around on the jQuery website there may be some plugins for you that could help achieve what you are looking for:

[Flexify](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Flexify) - This sounds like what you are looking for, lets you make fluid interfaces that take up the available space in a browser.

[Columizer](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Columnizer) - This lets you create newspaper column style layouts that resize with the browser

[All plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Plugins/category/51) in the layout category on jQuery

Hope that helps, someday I have to spend some more time with jQuery ><